# Lisp array element swap

Tags: arrays, position, lisp

I'm new to lisp and I'm trying to trade two elements in an array. I would like to know if there is a function to get a specified position so I can use rotatef to swap them.

I've tried the function position but it doesn't work on arrays since it isn't a sequence.

What is the best computational solution in case there isn't a built in function for array?

I've searched around and can't seem to find a simple solution. Is row-major-aref the solution?

Basically, i want to find the position of an element in the 2 dimensional array and return the position to be used in rotatef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should work - arrays are indeed sequences.

```
(let* ((an-array (make-array 6 :initial-contents '(#\f #\o #\o #\b #\a #\r)))
       (f-pos (position #\f an-array))
       (r-pos (position #\r an-array)))
  (rotatef (elt an-array f-pos)
           (elt an-array r-pos))
  an-array)
;=> #(#\r #\o #\o #\b #\a #\f)
```

Of course, you don't need to bind the positions to names. This will work too:

```
(let ((an-array (make-array 6 :initial-contents '(#\f #\o #\o #\b #\a #\r))))
  (rotatef (elt an-array (position #\f an-array))
           (elt an-array (position #\r an-array)))
  an-array)
;=> #(#\r #\o #\o #\b #\a #\f)
```

If the problem is with `position` not finding the element you need, its `:test` argument may be helpful. There are also `position-if` and `position-if-not` functions which let you supply your own predicate for identifying the element. All three are described [here](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_pos_p.htm) in the HyperSpec.

Here's an example that probably won't work without the `:test` argument, since the default (which is [`eql`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_eql.htm) for all sequence functions with `:test` arguments - see table 11-2 [here](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/collections.html) for a nice summary of the standard sequence function keyword arguments) doesn't work on lists.

```
(let ((an-array (make-array 3 :initial-contents '((1 2 3)
                                                  (4 5 6)
                                                  (7 8 9)))))
  (rotatef (elt an-array (position '(1 2 3) an-array :test #'equal))
           (elt an-array (position '(7 8 9) an-array :test #'equal)))
  an-array)
;=> ((7 8 9) (4 5 6) (1 2 3))
```

(Tested on SBCL 1.0.55.0.debian).

**Added:**

Here's a brute force way to do it with a two-dimensional array. `find-position` assumes the array is of size `(3  3)` but it would be easy to make it somewhat more general.

I don't advocate this as the best solution, but I didn't want to leave you empty handed after misunderstanding your question :)

```
(defvar an-array #2A((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9)))

(defun find-position (array item &key (test #'eql))
  (loop for i below 3 do
        (loop for j below 3 do
              (when (funcall test (aref array i j) item)
                (return-from find-position (list i j))))))

(defun swap-4-and-7 (array)
  ;; Example use
  (destructuring-bind (i1 j1) (find-position array 4)
    (destructuring-bind (i2 j2) (find-position array 7)
      (rotatef (aref array i1 j1)
               (aref array i2 j2))))
  array)

(swap-4-and-7 an-array)
;=> #2A((1 2 3) (7 5 6) (4 8 9))
```

Comment: Can't seem to make it work either. Is there a difference between make-array '(3 3) and make-array 3? Because I'm passed a make-array '(3 3) and when I try position it says its a non-sequence.

I'm supposed to receive a 2 dimension NxN array with numbers and nil and want to discover the nil. In your last example, position works because you search for a list, not a number inside that list, like 2. And on first two examples, they are both vectors that are considered sequences and hence position works. However if it's a 2 dimensional array lisp considers it a non-sequence

Comment: Indeed, that's true. I didn't realize you're working with a two-dimensional array. You may want to add it more explicitly to your question (though Rainer seems to have understood so maybe it was just me!)

Comment: @d0pe, I added a brute force approach that would work on a two-dimensional array (similar to what you had in mind in your comment to Rainer I think). I haven't had the occasion to work with multidimensional arrays in CL so there's likely a better way - I'd recommend continuing to look into Rainer's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the time taken. I had just solved it on my own, with loops, my when claus was the problem. Your answer works aswell. Thanks again

Comment: Only one-dimensional arrays are sequences.

Comment: Note also that it is not a good idea to modify literal data. Effects are unspecified in ANSI Common Lisp.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a one-dimensional displaced array and use that as a vector for `position`.

Example:

```
CL-USER 9 > (let ((a0 (make-array '(2 3)
                                  :initial-contents '((foo1 bar foo2)
                                                      (foo3 baz foo4)))))
              (let ((a1 (make-array (reduce #'+ (array-dimensions a0))
                                    :displaced-to a0)))
                (let ((pos1 (position 'baz a1))
                      (pos2 (position 'bar a1)))
                  (when (and pos1 pos2)
                    (rotatef (aref a1 pos1)
                             (aref a1 pos2)))))
              a0)
#2A((FOO1 BAZ FOO2) (FOO3 BAR FOO4))
```

Comment: Hey Rainer, thanks for the tip. This works but now I can't swap them efficiently. I can always turn the position back to array coordinates to use on rotatef but doesn't seem logical.

Also, how do I turn back from one dimensional array to two dimensions?

Can't I loop through the array and return when I find the nil? I tried with (loop for i from 0 to N do (loop for j from 0 to N do (when (eq (aref an-array i j) nil) (return (list i j)))) but doesn't seem to work

Comment: @d0pe: sure you can easily swap them. Swap them using the displaced array using rotatef. Also you don't need to turn back anything. The displaced array is a new array which references the original array.